# travis CI how to create DB?

Tags: mysql, junit, travis-ci

**.travis.yml file is**

```
language: java
sudo: required

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: historyboard
  username: root
  encoding: utf8

before_script:
  - echo "USE mysql;\nUPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('test') WHERE user='root';\nFLUSH PRIVILEGES;\n" | mysql -u root
  - mysql -e 'create database IF NOT EXISTS BOARD_DB;'
  - mysql -e "use BOARD_DB;"


  - mysql -e "USE mysql;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS board;

    CREATE TABLE board (
      b_index int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      email varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
      password varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      w_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      content text,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_index)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"
```

i add create DB script in travis.yml file

but in travis CI build Junit Test can't load table `BOARD_DB.board`

how to add MySQL DB and Table for JUnit TestCase in Travis CI?

**TEST error log is**

```
### SQL: INSERT INTO board         (             email,              password,              w_date,              content         )         VALUES         (             ?,              ?,              now(),              ?         )
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'BOARD_DB.board' doesn't exist
```

how to fix this Travis CI build error?

Comment: Can you provide the link to your TravisCI build?